# How exactly transactions work in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, transactions, insertion

I've read that creating `for insert trigger` creates transaction implicitly. So I can rollback transaction from within trigger and "undo" the insert.

Is that so?

```sql
create trigger TRIGGER_NAME 
on TABLE_NAME
for insert
as
    declare @someVar = ....

    if @someVar > 0 
    begin
        rollback transaction
    end
```

So in that case, if `@someVar` is greater than 0, insert will be cancelled, right?

```sql
create trigger TRIGGER_NAME 
on TABLE_NAME
for insert
as
    begin transaction
        declare @someVar = ....

        if @someVar > 0    
        begin
            rollback transaction
        end

        commit transaction
```

In that case, insert would be also cancelled, right?

What happens when we have two `for insert trigger` for the same table, and both of them do `rollback transaction` do they share the same implicit transaction?

I came across some complications with that matter, so I tried creating my own explicit transaction in every trigger, but with `begin transaction` I just can't do anything to use `inserted` properly, I can't extract any value from it.

Comment: **DO NOT** create your own transaction inside a trigger!!!! Never ever..... the trigger **runs in the context** (and the transaction) of the statement (`INSERT`) that caused it to fire. Yes - if you check certain conditions and want to abort, you can do a `ROLLBACK` and cancel that transaction. But NEVER EVER create your own "sub-transactions" inside a trigger!

Comment: @marc_s Okay. Is there any way I can nest transactions one in another? When I call function in function (for example procedure to insert record to table, which invokes for insert trigger. Both procedure and trigger use transactions. Rolling back in trigger rollsback all the way to the first transaction, which is not what i want)

Comment: No - SQL Server has the *syntax* for nested transactions - unfortunately, it is lacking the proper functionality. If you rollback in a nested transaction, that rollback affects all transactions all the way to the outermost one

Comment: @marc_s So it's impossible to nest transactions the way i desired? There is nothing I can do, right?

Comment: That is correct - SQL Server currently **does not** support nested / independent transactions. Your trigger always executes in the context of the transaction of the SQL statement that caused it to fire - and you can only roll back that transaction if you need to (and thus cancel **all** inserts - you cannot differentiate between rows) - can't be more specific / detailed than that....

Comment: @marc_s Is it a bad design choice to nest begin tran in every procedur, but use 
```sql
if @@trancount > 0 begin
    rollback tran
```
?

Comment: The concept of "nested transaction" does not really exists. There is one and only transaction because it is the state of the session. By definition a transaction is an atomic scope of the execution of code. You cannot have simultaneously atomic and partially atomic !

Comment: @marc_s So I came up with strategy like that for managing nested procedurs. If something is wrong, it will fall back raising errors and will rollback everything.
https://pastebin.com/Dh9Aqw8A
Is it ok?

Comment: Maybe you're "abusing" triggers - a trigger should be **very small and nimble** - you should **NOT** be doing any complicated processing, and calling external services, or anything like that. The trigger executes in the context of the SQL statement and extends its runtime - therefore, it should be **really quick**; make a quick insert into an audit table or something like that - definitely **nothing** that would require extensive transaction handling....

Comment: @marc_s noo, of course. Im using triggers to check if I can insert record (for example in my project, Im making database for restaurant. I have to check if table is free before inserting booking). But procedures can call other procedurs in which I insert.
`procedure -> procedure -> insert`
And I want rollback in that insert to rollback all that procedures. My pastebin do exactly that. So im asking is it good?

Comment: @Knaider... Using a trigger in such a case (checking if table is free), seems to me unfortunate because you can do it by the design of the data model with some UNIQUE constraint. As an example, you can create a reservation schedule table, with an entry every 15 minutes for each table (uniqueness) and with a single bit valued at 0 or 1 knowing if it is free (0) or reserved (1). So no trigger will be used and query to find free tables much more easy to write and quicker to execute...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact a transaction is the state of the session. Nothing else. So you can be in a transaction sate or not. When you execute a SQL query (which is different from "command") there is an implicite transaction that encloses the query. When you are inside the trigger code, the transaction state is alive, and you can rollback it or commit. If any of this command (COMMIT or ROLLBACK) is executed in the trigger code, you will raise an execption... But the transacation state no more exists, until you execute any query.

Now if you have several trigger, there is a precedence in the serial execution of the trigger that you can manage with the procedure sp_settriggerorder.

Having multiple triggers for the same action is not recommanded, except when you have to execute them in a specific order. As an example I give in my courses, I limit to three the number of trigger for the same action, with this peculiar precedence :

1. trigger for set based constraint
2. trigger for operational process (client application)
3. trigger for tracking

Comment: What about `commit tran` then? Is it also going to set @@trancount to 0?

Comment: I came up with something like this to manage raising error. 

https://pastebin.com/Dh9Aqw8A

It just fallsback and reverse everything in case of some error (ofc insert is made to rollback just for tests sake)
I'd like to use that stretegy in my University project. Is that good idea?

Comment: COMMIT TRAN decrease the deep level @@TRANCOUNT until this level come to zero, then really COMMIT. ROLLBACK cancel the transaction and set the deep level @@TRANCOUT to zero. This is well know in technical litterature as the "asymetric model for nested transaction management"

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220593707_A_Nested_Transaction_Model_for_Multilevel_Secure_Database_Management_Systems